# iPhone rangeOfString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Hello
I have a string like this:

```
Results for: 123D12 
2010

2009

2008

2007

2006

YEAR: 2006 WEEK: 2 PRODIDNUM: 37911
 ACCESSKEY: FA3540B52F

2005

2004

YEAR: 2004 WEEK: 22 PRODIDNUM: 46178
 ACCESSKEY: 58B2509373
```

and I want to spot the ACCESSKEY to help me get the hexadecimal(in this case are FA3540B52F and 58B2509373).

The issue is that when I use rangeOfString to get the accesskey it stops only to the first one! This is my code:

```
if ([strippedString rangeOfString:@"ACCESSKEY"].location != NSNotFound ) {
    NSUInteger int1=[strippedString rangeOfString:@"ACCESSKEY"].location;

    NSString *finssid = [strippedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(int1+11,10)];
    NSLog(@"Output = Found it %d \n",int1);

    NSLog(@"Output =%@ \n \n",finssid);    
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [strippedString length]);
BOOL keepGoing = YES;

// Find all ssid
while (keepGoing) {
    NSRange accessWord = [strippedString rangeOfString:@"ACCESSKEY" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];
    if (accessWord.location != NSNotFound) {
        // since we have found the access key, we can assume somethings
        // ACCESSKEY: FA3540B52F
        int pos = accessWord.location + 11;
        NSString *ssid = [strippedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos, pos + 10)];

        NSLog(@"SSID: %@", ssid);

        // reset our search up a little for our next loop around
        searchRange = NSMakeRange(pos, [strippedString length] - pos);
    } else {
        keepGoing = NO;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: It should be working but I am getting this error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: OK I fix it! You wrote this:         NSString *ssid = [strippedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos, pos + 10)];                  instead of this:
           NSString *fssid = [strippedString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos,10)];

Answer (score 1):

Use `rangeOfString:options:range:` instead of `rangeOfString:`. Save the index you found a match at, then using the `range:` argument start on the index after that.  This way you loop through and previous matches fall outside the range you are looking in.

Comment: I have read about this but I didnt figure out how to implement it. can you give me an example pleasE?

Comment: Not sure of the exact format myself, just looked it up in the docs.  What part specifically didn't you figure out?

Comment: This part:if ([strippedString rangeOfString:@"ACCESSKEY"].location != NSNotFound ) Actually it stops on the frist ACCESSKEY and I want to find all keys in the string.