# getting the position of character in NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am trying to get the position of Characters in NSString using the rangeOfString method.
For example if I have the word "BEER" I am looking to get the positions of the letter E in the string so I should get position 1 and 2
rangeOfString only gives me the first occurrence of the letter

```
NSRange range = [word rangeOfString:letter];

NSLog(@"Word is %@ Range is %d" , word, range.location);
```

So i only get location 1

is there another method I can use or do I have to use NSScanner for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it works, according to the documentation: `rangeOfString` only returns the first occurrence of the string you pass in.

You could either use `[rangeOfString:options:range:][1]` and iterate over the results provided by it each time specifying a proper value for the `range` parameter, or you could use the `NSRegularExpression` class.

You can get a sample code for the first approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425812/iphone-rangeofstring) and for the second [here](http://remarkablepixels.com/blog/2011/1/13/regular-expressions-on-ios-nsregularexpression.html).